# Find out many times a substring appears when one letter could be anything

Tags: python

I’m trying to count the number of times ‘code’ appears in a substring, however the ‘d’ can be any letter so ‘cope’ and ‘coze’ would also count. I’m just learning Python and I’m sure this is very simple and probably a regex would work, but the exercise I’m doing doesn’t call for it. This is just a practice problem on a site, not for school or anything. Any help would be appreciated. I’ve tried every way I can think of. This is my latest, but it errors and says list out of range My code looks like:

```
def count_code(str):
   sum = o
   for i in range(len(str)-1):
     if str[i:i+1] == ‘co’ and str[i+4] == ‘e’:
       sum += 1
     else:
       sum = 0
   return sum
```

the call would be:

```
count_code(‘codeeoedeeicoze’)
```

Error: string index out of range

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Try picking a value of `i` and see what results you get for `str[i:i+1]` and `str[i+4]`. Do they match what you expect? Can you see why?

Comment: You should definetly not use sum and str as variables/parameters as these are keywords.

Comment: Also, fancy quotation marks like `‘` and `’` are not valid. If your code is running at all, it presumably doesn't contain them; double-check what's going on with how  you paste the code to SO.

Comment: Kari - I’m not sure why it pasted like that. I’m using normal single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or here a code closer to yours, but there were some assorted issues:

```
def count_code(word):
   result = 0
   for i in range(len(word)-3):
       if word[i:i+2] == "co" and word[i+3] == "e":
           result += 1
   return result

print(count_code('codeeoedeeicoze'))
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to better understand the -3 part. :) I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all "co" occurrences via `re.finditer`. After that you loop through the found indexes and check if the 4th letter would be an "e"

To reiterate, you should definitely not use sum and str as variables/parameters as these are keywords.

```
    def count_code(code):
    import re
    sum_l = 0
    items = [ m.start() for m in re.finditer('co', code)] 
    for item in items: 
        if item+3 < len(code): 
            if code[item+3] == "e":
                sum_l += 1
    return sum_l

print(count_code("codeeoedeeicoze"))
OUT: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

first and foremost, it is not advisable to use `str` as formal parameter. try this

```py
def count_code(s):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(s) - 3):
        if s[i : i + 2] == "co" and s[i + 3 : i + 4] == "e":
            sum = sum + 1
    return sum


print(count_code("codeeoedeeicoze"))
```

Comment: I didn't write the function. It's on a site called codebat and the str was what they used. I personally don't use str as I know its a keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: maybe you can inform them that this is bad practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lists are 0-indices. The solution you have there are index based solutions. I would say a more pythonic way is use the zip function. And don't worry about index bound errors again.

```
def func(str):
    count = 1
    for c1, c2, c4 in zip(str[0:-3], str[1:-2], str[3:]):
        if c1 == 'c' and c2 == 'o' and c4 == 'e':
            count += 1
    return count
```